# how does file reading ( streaming ) really work in mule?

Tags: mule, streaming, dataweave, mule4

Am trying to understand how streaming works w.r.t mule 4.4.
Am reading a large file and am using 'Repeating file store stream' as streaming strategy
'In memory size' = 128 KB
[image]

The file is 24 MB and for sake of argument lets say 1000 records is equivalent to 128 KB
so about 1000 records will be stored in memory and rest all will be written to file store by mule .

Here's the flow:
[image]

At stage#1 we are reading a file
At stage#2 we are logging payload - so I am assuming initially 128KB worth of data is logged and internally mule will move rest of the data from file storage to in memory and this data will be written to log.
Question : so does the heap memory increase from 128KB to 24 MB ?
I am assuming no , but needed confirmation ?

At stage#3 we are using transform script to create a json payload
So what happens here :
so now is the json payload all in memory now ? ( say 24 MB ) ?
what has happened to the stream ?

so really I am struggling to understand how stream is beneficial if during transformation the data is stored in memory ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how each component works but usually logging means to load the full payload in memory. Having said that, logging 'big' payloads is considered a bad practice and you should avoid doing it in the first place. Even a few KBs logs are really not a good idea. Logs are not intended to be used that way. Using logs, as any computational operation, have a cost in processing and resource usage. I have seen several times people causing out of memory errors or performance issues because of excessive logging.

The case with the Transform component is different. In some cases it is able to benefit from streaming, depending on the format used and the script. Sequential access to records is required for streaming to work. If you try an indexed access to the 24MB payload it will probably load the entire payload in memory (example `payload[14203]`). Also referencing the payload more than once in a step may fail. Streamed records are consumed after being read so it is not possible to use them twice.

Streaming for Dataweave needs to be enabled (it is not the default) by using the property `streaming=true`.

You can find more details in the documentation for [DataWeave Streaming](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dataweave-streaming) and [Mule Streaming](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.4/streaming-about).